# Slater Determinant in Python package

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

Is there any library functions which I could use in python to construct slater determinant? Can someone suggest me something to fix this issue ? Is it really possible to determinant with functions as elements of the determinant ?

Comment: Maybe https://www.sympy.org/ can be of help.